# Crop sub-section of 2d Array to a new 2d arry?

Tags: c#

```
        int[,] cells = new int[,]
        {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        };
```

Hello, i have this 2D array of intergers, i want to crop out the the values to a new 2D array.
What i should end up with is:

```
         1 0 0
         3 0 2
         0 4 6
         0 6 0
```

What I have is the following, It works if the 2D array is surrounded by 1 row and 1 column. But stops working of the rows and columns increase.

```
    public static int[,] Trim2DArray(int[,] fArray, int n)
    {
        List<int> rangeX = new List<int>();
        List<int> rangeY = new List<int>();
        int[,] corrArray = new int[,]{};
        
        if(n == 0)
        {
            return fArray;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < fArray.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < fArray.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    if(fArray[y,x] > 0)
                    {
                        rangeX.Add(x);
                        rangeY.Add(y);
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            int xm = rangeX.Min();
            int ym = rangeY.Min();
            int xM = rangeX.Max();
            int yM = rangeY.Max();
            
             corrArray = new int[xM,yM];
            
            for(int col = 0; col <= corrArray.GetLength(0)-yM; col++)
            {
                for(int row = 0; row <= corrArray.GetLength(1)-xM; row++)
                {
                    corrArray[col, row] = fArray[col + xm, row + ym];
                }
            }
        }
        
        return corrArray;
    }
```

Comment: "But stops working of the rows and columns increase."  In what way does it stop working?  Is there an error message?  If there is, please quote the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made few mistakes.
Firstly `corrArray` starts at 0 and ends at `xM` and `yM`, so it is too big by `xm - 1` and `ym - 1` respectively. The `-1` is neccessay in case `xm==xM` or `ym==yM` - this might happen if only a single row or column has positive numbers. This is the correct way:

```
corrArray = new int[xM + 1- xm, yM + 1 - ym];
```

Secondly, you loop indexing wrong.

```
for (int col = 0; col < corrArray.GetLength(0); col++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < corrArray.GetLength(1); row++)
    {
        corrArray[col, row] = fArray[col + xm, row + ym];
    }
}
```

You might also consider abandoning list usage, as it's completely unnecessary:

```
private static int[,] Trim2DArray(int[,] fArray)
{
    var startY = -1;
    var startX = -1;
    var endY = -1;
    var endX = -1;

    for (int x = 0; x < fArray.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < fArray.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            if (fArray[x, y] != 0)
            {
                if (startX == -1) startX = x;
                if (startY == -1) startY = y;
                if (x > endX) endX = x;
                if (y > endY) endY = y;
            }
        }
    }

    if (startX == -1)
    {
        return new int[0,0];
    }

    var crop = new int[endX - startX + 1, endY - startY + 1];

    for (int x = 0; x < crop.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < crop.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            crop[x, y] = fArray[x + startX, y + startY];
        }
    }

    return crop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea but you only need to track the four corners rather than building a list of all cells with data.

Here's an example which works for any number of rows and columns.

```
private static int[,] Trim2DArray(int[,] fArray)
{
    var startY = -1;
    var startX = -1;
    var endY = -1;
    var endX = -1;

    for (int x = 0; x < fArray.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < fArray.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            if (fArray[x, y] != 0)
            {
                if (startX == -1) startX = x;
                if (startY == -1) startY = y;
                if (x > endX) endX = x;
                if (y > endY) endY = y;
            }
        }
    }

    if (startX == -1)
    {
        return new int[0,0];
    }

    var crop = new int[endX - startX + 1, endY - startY + 1];

    for (int x = 0; x < crop.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < crop.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            crop[x, y] = fArray[x + startX, y + startY];
        }
    }

    return crop;
}
```